# Expected to decode Int but found an array instead

Tags: json, swift, api

I can get all the other data without any problem, but I could not get **genre_ids** because of its an array type. How can get array types ?

As an extra information, it gives 20 results for a single query (page) on the site where I pulled the data. It remains to use loops to get the whole result, which takes a lot of time. Is there any way to speed this up? (without recommending another site)
https://developers.themoviedb.org/3/movies/get-top-rated-movies

**Error :**

> Expected to decode Int but found an array instead

**Model :**

```
struct json : Decodable {
    let page : Int
    let total_results : Int
    let total_pages : Int
    let results : [Results]
}

struct Results : Decodable {
    let vote_average : Double
    let title : String
    let overview : String
    let poster_path : String
    let genre_ids : Int
}
```

**Json data :**

```
    "page": 1,
  "results": [
    {
      "poster_path": "/9O7gLzmreU0nGkIB6K3BsJbzvNv.jpg",
      "adult": false,
      "overview": "Framed in the 1940s for the double murder of his wife and her lover, upstanding banker Andy Dufresne begins a new life at the Shawshank prison, where he puts his accounting skills to work for an amoral warden. During his long stretch in prison, Dufresne comes to be admired by the other inmates -- including an older prisoner named Red -- for his integrity and unquenchable sense of hope.",
      "release_date": "1994-09-10",
      "genre_ids": [
        18,
        80
      ],
      "id": 278,
      "original_title": "The Shawshank Redemption",
      "original_language": "en",
      "title": "The Shawshank Redemption",
      "backdrop_path": "/xBKGJQsAIeweesB79KC89FpBrVr.jpg",
      "popularity": 6.741296,
      "vote_count": 5238,
      "video": false,
      "vote_average": 8.32
    },
    {
      "poster_path": "/lIv1QinFqz4dlp5U4lQ6HaiskOZ.jpg",
      "adult": false,
      "overview": "Under the direction of a ruthless instructor, a talented young drummer begins to pursue perfection at any cost, even his humanity.",
      "release_date": "2014-10-10",
      "genre_ids": [
        18,
        20,
        22
      ],
      "id": 244786,
      "original_title": "Whiplash",
      "original_language": "en",
      "title": "Whiplash",
      "backdrop_path": "/6bbZ6XyvgfjhQwbplnUh1LSj1ky.jpg",
      "popularity": 10.776056,
      "vote_count": 2059,
      "video": false,
      "vote_average": 8.29
    }
```

**Decoding :**

```
func jsonStart() -> ([String] , [String] , [Double] , [String] , [Int])  {
    var page : Int = 1
    var titles: [String] = []
    var overviews : [String] = []
    var vote_average : [Double] = []
    var poster_path : [String] = []
    var genre_ids : [Int] = []
    while (page <= 20) {
        let addressUrl = URL(string: "https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/top_rated?api_key=key&language=tr-TR&page=\(page)&region=TR")
        let data = try! Data(contentsOf: addressUrl!)
        let decoder = JSONDecoder()

            let dt = try! decoder.decode(json.self, from: data)
            let movie = dt.results
            for i in 0..<movie.count {
                titles.append(movie[i].title)
                overviews.append(movie[i].overview)
                vote_average.append(movie[i].vote_average)
                poster_path.append(movie[i].poster_path)
                genre_ids.append(movie[i].genre_ids)
                
            }
        page+=1
    }
        return (titles , overviews , vote_average , poster_path , genre_ids)
    }
```

Comment: in your model `genre_ids` is an `Int`, but in the JSON it's an array

Comment: Try making it an array: `let genre_ids: [Int]`

Comment: @pawello2222 I tried this, but in the decoding part, how do I append it to array?

Comment: @EmreYıldırım In the decoding part, you can use `genre_ids += movie[i].genre_ids` if you want to add all **movie[i].genre_ids** values into **genre_ids**

Comment: What you are doing here is completely wrong, you are taking an array of a struct and splits it into several arrays. This will make your code much harder to work with and maintain. Instead you should return your `movies` array and use that in the rest of your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just modify your model to be like this:

```
struct Results : Decodable {
    let vote_average: Double
    let title: String
    let overview: String
    let poster_path: String
    let genre_ids: [Int]
}
```

When you iterate over the `Results` items you can use `append(contentsOf:)` function to append all the items of an array to another one:

```
for i in 0..<movie.count {
    genre_ids.append(contentsOf: movie[i].genre_ids)
}
```

**Update**: As [@JoakimDanielson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63853950/expected-to-decode-int-but-found-an-array-instead/63854034#comment112915828_63853950) mentioned in the comments you can use a better practice and return the movies as an array of `Results`, like this:

```
func jsonStart() -> [Results] {
    var page : Int = 1
    var movies: [Results] = []
    let decoder = JSONDecoder()
    while (page <= 20) {
        let addressUrl = URL(string: "https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/top_rated?api_key=key&language=tr-TR&page=\(page)&region=TR")
        do {
            let data = try Data(contentsOf: addressUrl!)
            let dt = try decoder.decode(json.self, from: data)
            movies.append(contentsOf: dt.results)
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
        page += 1
    }
    return movies
}
```

Comment: thanks but there is a problem. Some movies have 2 genres_ids, while 3 or more other ones. This is a bit confusing here.

Comment: @EmreYıldırım sorry, I didn't understand. What is the problem of an array having 2, 3 or even more items?

Comment: There are gender id values for movies. These values ​​determine the category of the movie. Some movies contain only one category, while others can contain several categories. For example : id 28 is "action" , id 12 is "adventure" . So for the first data (The Shawshank Redemption), it should return [18,80] when I print genre_ids [0] . I apologize for writing long.

Comment: @EmreYıldırım so, you don't want to mix all the `genre_ids` together in one array? or the decoding is not successful?

Comment: no it works but its confusing to categorize movies. movies [0] = "The Shawshank Redemption" ,  genre_id [0] = [18.80] should have been. But genre_id [0] return just '18'. You can understand better if you look at the link. Each movie has more than one category, we have to separate them from each other :  [link](https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/top_rated?api_key=5a89c07838e91d57f99884f9f6bfa290&language=tr-TR&page=1&region=TR)

Comment: @EmreYıldırım you can probably use an array of arrays `[[Int]]` to store genre_ids, but as [Joakim Danielson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63853950/expected-to-decode-int-but-found-an-array-instead/63854034#comment112915828_63853950) said, you are making it more and more complex. Why you are not try to return you movies as an array of `[Results]`?

Comment: I could not understand . How?

Comment: Unfortunately its given error : Expected to decode Array<Any> but found a number instead

Comment: How can I reach ? It's giving error like that :
`let a = jsonStart()`
`let b = a.title`

Comment: @EmreYıldırım no, you are getting an array of `Results` from the `jsonStart()` function. Try `let movies = jsonStart()` `movies[0].title` and so on.

Comment: thanks. but unfortunately we could not solve the main problem. Categorization of movies Grouping event :)

Comment: How do you want to categorise your movies? How would you have done that with your arrays in your question? Please, update your question.

Comment: look at the json data again . I updated ... Our first movie is "The Shawshank Redemption" and its genre ids (film categories) is [18,80] . Second film is "Whiplash", genres is [18,20,22].   Now when I print movies [0] , it will print the shawshank. Its okay. But when I print genres_ids it will print just 18. it would be [18,80]. Because otherwise the value of 80 will be like the second movie

Comment: @EmreYıldırım please, explain in your question what exactly you want to achieve. How would you like to use your data?

Comment: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63855020/get-a-json-data-containing-array-separately)

Comment: @EmreYıldırım so, using the above code. When you do this `let movies = jsonStart()` `print(movies[0].genre_ids)` you are getting only 18 ? I just tried the code in playground and returns `[18, 80]`.

Comment: it worked now. Thank you very much, you worked hard with me :)

Comment: No problem. Happy to help.